# Laravel FormRequest on PUT request failing

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a RESTful API with Laravel 5.8 I am using FormRequests to validate the users input to my POST & PUT requests. The POST works absolutely perfectly, but the PUT request are failing with the following error,

> "message": "Too few arguments to function App\Http\Requests\ProjectStoreRequest::Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\{closure}(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"

The method my PUT requests gets routed looks like this (and the URL is /api/projects/{id}),

```
public function update(ProjectStoreRequest $request, $id)
{
     $validated = $request->validate();
     $project  = Project::find($id);

     $project->title = $request->title;
     $project->due_date = Carbon::parse(strtotime($request->due_date))->format('Y-m-d');

     $project->save();

     return response()->json(['message' => 'Project updated', 'data' => $project], 200);
}
```

And the ProjectStoreRequest looks like this,

```
    class ProjectStoreRequest extends FormRequest
    {
       /**
       * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
       *
       * @return bool
       */
       public function authorize()
       {
           return true;
       }

       /**
       * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
       *
       * @return array
       */
       public function rules()
       {
           return [
               'title' => 'required|string',
               'due_date' => 'date'
           ];
       }
   }
```

Comment: What happens if you change `ProjectStoreRequest` to `Request` to try if it gets inside the method? Can you show us your `<form>` in your blade and related route?

Comment: If I have `ProjectStoreRequest to Request` and comment out `$validated = $request->validate()` the method runs fine. There is no blade template the client sends JSON.

Comment: `$request->validate()` should be `$request->validated()` (it's missing the `d` on the end).

Comment: Talk about embarrasing!